# What is the difference between "It's deleted something" and "It deletes something"?

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs

Which one of the mentioned terms is the correct form of saying, for describing something that happens after we do something?

Example:

1. you can see **it deletes** the first name property
2. you can see **it's deleted** the first name property

The second example comes from, or **came after?**, an actual sentence from an online course instructed by a native English speaker for a real-time example of something from computer science.

If I was the instructor, I would probably use the term "it deletes" because it happens when I'm explaining the concept.

Comment: Sentence 2 means: "*you can see **it has deleted** the first name property*". Does that help you understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is the case with much of English usage, the correctness of these examples is highly dependent upon the context in which they are used.

> 1. you can see [that] it deletes the first name property

Here you are describing something *as it happens*.
It would be correct to say this at *about the same time* as you push the button.

> 2. you can see it [… has] deleted the first name property

Here you are describing something that has *already happened*.
It would be correct to say this *after* you have pushed the button.

Both statements are grammatically correct.
Which one is appropriate for the situation depends upon how you are presenting things.
Whichever one you use should be used consistently with other similar statements given during the lesson.

> I would probably use the term "it deletes" because it happens when I'm explaining the concept

Exactly.